# hazelcast, mongodb persistance cannot find _id

Tags: java, mongodb, persistence, hazelcast

In my mapstore, hazelcast loads all the keys form my MongoDB

```
@Override
public Iterable<String> loadAllKeys() {
    System.out.println("LoadAllKeys");
    List<String> keys = new LinkedList<String>();
    FindIterable<Document> ids = collection.find().projection(Projections.include("_id"));
    for (Document document : ids) {
        keys.add(document.get("_id").toString());
    }
    return keys;
}
```

The problem comes when it tries loading those keys as objects. It always gives me back an empty list:

```
@Override
public Map<String, MyObj > loadAll(Collection<String> keys) {
    System.out.println("LoadAll " + keys);
    HashMap<String, MyObj > result = new HashMap<String, MyObj >();
    FindIterable<Document> id = collection.find(in("_id", keys));
    for (Document document : id) {
        String name = (String) document.get("name");

        MyObj myObj= new MyObj();
        myObj.setname(name);

        result.put(document.get("_id").toString(), myObj);
    }
    return result;
}
```

The reason it is because my collection object the _id is wrapped by ObjectId. E.g:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("59b7dac41944ac39f8a299c3")
```

Can you guys tell me where I am going wrong? I used this link as a ref:
https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/hazelcast-integration/mongodb

Thanks

Comment: Does your object MyObj implement Serializable or any of the Hazelcast serialization?

Comment: Yes, it does implement java io serializable

Comment: What is the size of result map in loadAll before it is returned?